# View nodes in a listing only, not on their own?

Tags: nodes

I have created two node-types: 'match' and 'set'. When a 'match' node is viewed it displays a listing of several 'set' nodes. I've acheived this by calling `node_load_multiple` in `hook_node_view`. That's all 'set' nodes do: they are listed by a match node. 'Set' nodes can be created, edited and deleted, but I only want the user to be able to view them in listings.

So, I want to deny access to viewing 'set' nodes on their own page at node/1 or whatever. I've denied access to 'set' nodes using the node access mechanism, but then they don't appear in my listing either.

How can I set these nodes so that they can only be viewed in my listing?

The only thing I can think of is not to call `node_load_multiple` but to write by own `db_select` query to retrieve all the necessary 'set' nodes to list in a match 'node': a bit messy.

Hope this makes sense. I open to any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm 100% certain this question has been asked before, though I can't find it ATM. Page manager can hide content types for you. So can Rabbit Hole, but I strongly dislike that type of "single use" modules, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: I agree about using modules to do one task, if, with a bit of effort, you can write a few lines of code to do the same. However, Rabbit Hole sounds perfect. The other options seem to involve bypassing the node module. I like the 'unpublish the node' idea. I could do this and the then write my own db query. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the [node_view hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7).  In that hook you can check for the node type (set) and view mode (full) and add your logic.  If you're using a reference field to relate the set to the match then you could probably redirect the user back to the match.

When you're listing sets on the match page you could also not render them as links a user doesn't try to view the set directly.